# How to push all the selected values of checkbox in an array in React-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-bootstrap

I am using a react-bootstrap component `Checkbox` to create a general form . The component name is **AdminPage**, I wanted tp pass all the selected values of the checkboxes into an state (which is initialised as a state ). I am unable to do so.

Here below is the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Row, Col, Dropdown, Form } from "react-bootstrap";


export const AdminPage = () => {

const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [operations, setOperation] = useState([]);

const handleSubmit = () => {
  alert("Selected Checkboxes -" + operations);
}

return (
                <>
                    <div className="p-3 border border-dark bg-light ">
                        <h3 className="text-center">Add Roles Here</h3>
                        <Form className="p-3">
                            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicText">
                                <Form.Label column sm="3">
                                    Name
                                </Form.Label>
                                <Col sm="9">
                                    <Form.Control type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter Name here..." />
                                </Col>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicText">
                                <Form.Label column sm="3">
                                    Opeations
                                </Form.Label>
                                {/* <Col sm="9">
                                    <Form.Control type="text" value={rolecredentials.operations} onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "operations")} placeholder='Eg: GETitems, GETstocks, GETpinfences, GETinventory, ADDinventory' />
                                    <Form.Text className="text-muted mx-2">
                                        Mention multiple values using comma seperator like given in placeholder
                                    </Form.Text>
                                </Col> */}
                                <Col sm="8">
                                    <Form value={operations} >
                                    <div key={`inline-checkbox`} className="mb-3">
                                        <Form.Check
                                            inline
                                            label="GETitem"
                                            name="group1"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            value="GETitem"
                                            
                                            id={`inline-checkbox-1`}
                                        />
                                        <Form.Check
                                            inline
                                            label="GETstocks"
                                            name="group1"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            value="GETstocks"
                                            
                                            id={`inline-checkbox-2`}
                                        />
                                        <Form.Check
                                            inline
                                            label="GETpinfences"
                                            name="group1"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            value="GETpinfences"
                                            
                                            id={`inline-checkbox-3`}
                                        />
                                        <Form.Check
                                            inline
                                            label="GETinventory"
                                            name="group1"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            value="GETinventory"
                                            
                                            id={`inline-checkbox-4`}
                                        />
                                        <Form.Check
                                            inline
                                            label="ADDinventory"
                                            name="group1"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            value="ADDinventory"
                                          
                                            id={`inline-checkbox-5`}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    </Form>
                                </Col>
                            </Form.Group>
                            
                            <div className="w-25 m-auto mt-5 mb-3">
                                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                                    Add Role
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                        </Form>
                    </div>
                </>
            )
}
```

I had tried `onSelect` but still not able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Have you given the `:checked` pseudo selector a try?

```
const checkedElements = document.querySelectorAll(":checked");
```

*Edit*

Oh, and the event you're looking for is `onChange`.

*Edit**

```js
const handleSubmit = () => {
  alert("Selected Checkboxes -" + operations);

  const checkedElements = documents.querySelectorAll(":checked");
  

  checkedElements.forEach((entry) => {
    /*Here we have access to each checked element.
     *So maybe define an array, push each value you want to that array
     *and finally update the state after the forEach.
     */
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you share how to do so by my code?

Comment: I've edited my original answer. I don't know what type you have in your array, I assume it's a boolean? In that case just define a new array, add true for each iteration and finally update the state.

Comment: No the values in the array should be string. Like after selecting first & second checkbox, it should be like, `operation = ["GETitems", "GETstockpoints"]` .

Comment: Have a look at this proof of concept:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-rain-11hcr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: But it is showing that you can not read `forEach` property of null , since `selectedValues is [] ` initially

Comment: Yea well, clearly if nothing is checked, `querySelectorAll` returns null. So, either default to empty array with nullish coalescing or add a guard break:

`var selectedItems = document.querySelectorAll(":checked") ?? [];`

or

`if (!selectedElements) {return;}`

Updated the codepen, maybe that'll demonstrate it better.

Comment: Bro it is showing the error `TypeError: selectedItems.forEach is not a function`. When I printed the `selecteditems.value`, it is only showing the first selected element only

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you by any chance using `document.querySelector` and not `document.querySelectorAll`?

Comment: Ohkay I got it, thanks for the answer.
I upvoted it but showing `Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.`